# Backbone.js view instance variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm learning Backbone.js and am trying to figure out whether it's possible to have instance variables in Backbone views.

My goal is to load a view's templates from an external file when a view is being instantiated. Currently I'm storing them in a global variable in the Backbone app's global namespace, but it would be cleaner to store the templates in a view's instance variables. Currently I have it set up like this:

```
var templates = {};

MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        $.get('js/Test2Templates.tpl', function(doc) {

            var tmpls = $(doc).filter('template');

            templates['MessageView'] = [];

            tmpls.each(function() {
                templates.MessageView[this.id] = $.jqotec($.unescapeHTML(this.innerHTML));
            });
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        var tpldata = {name: 'Ville', thing: 'Finland'};
        $('#display').jqoteapp(templates.MessageView.greeting_template, tpldata);
    },

    events: {
        "click input[type=button]": "additionalTransactions"
    },

    additionalTransactions: function() {
        this.render();
    }

});
```

But instead of using "templates" being defined as a global var, I'd like to create 'templates' in a view's initialize function, along these lines (but this doesn't work):

```
MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({

    view_templates: {},

    initialize: function() {
        $.get('js/Test2Templates.tpl', function(doc) {

            var tmpls = $(doc).filter('template');

            tmpls.each(function() {
                this.view_templates[this.id] = $.jqotec($.unescapeHTML(this.innerHTML));
            });
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        var tpldata = {name: 'Ville', thing: 'Suomi'};
        $('#display').jqoteapp(this.view_templates.greeting_template, tpldata);
    },

    events: {
        "click input[type=button]": "additionalTransactions"
    },

    additionalTransactions: function() {
        this.render();
    }

});
```

This is probably (?) pretty straightforward and/or obvious, but me being somewhere on the Backbone.js learning curve, I'd much appreciate any help with this!! Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `view_templates` instance variable is fine (and a good idea as well). You just have to be sure that you're using the right `this` inside your `$.get()` callback and inside your `tmpls.each()` call. I think you want your `initialize` to look more like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.view_templates = { };

    var _this = this;
    $.get('js/Test2Templates.tpl', function(doc) {
        var tmpls = $(doc).filter('template');
        tmpls.each(function() {
            _this.view_templates[this.id] = $.jqotec($.unescapeHTML(this.innerHTML));
        });
    });
},
```

I'm not sure which `this.id` you want inside the `tmpls.each()` but I'm guessing that you want the DOM `id` attribute from the current template so I left it as `this.id`.

The `this.view_templates` assignment in your constructor (`initialize`) is needed because you presumably want each instance of the view to have its own copy of the array. Creating a new view instance doesn't do a deep copy of the the view so if you just have:

```
MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    view_templates: {},
    // ...
```

then all the instances will end up sharing the same `view_templates` object and `view_templates` will behave more like a class variable than an instance variable.

You can specify your instance variables in the view definition (i.e. the `Backbone.View.extend()` call) as a form of documentation but you will want to initialize any of them that should behave as an instance variable in your `initialize` method; read-only or "class variables" like `events` can be left as part of the view's definition.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for a thorough answer!! The key item I was missing (and that I hadn't tried) was `var self = this;` and then using 'self' instead of 'this' in the each loop. With that it is working as expected. Would you care to elaborate as to why 'this' can't be used within the loop? Does 'this' refer to the current loop instance (within the each loop) instead of the view instance?

Also, as you guessed, 'this.id' refers to the template's ID in the template file, like this:

`<template id="greeting_template">
...
</template>`

Comment: @Ville: A thorough question deserves a thorough answer :) The `this` inside the `.each` is the current DOM element, see the `.each` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/each/