# Backbone View extends is polluted

Tags: backbone.js, view

I have a view that represents a modal. This view has some attributes, like the footer extra class.
I'm having a trouble that, when some modal change it's value, all of them receive the same attribute.

This is the example:

```
var ModalView = AlertingView.extend({
    className : "modal",
    paramsTemplate: { footerClass: "" }   
});
```

After that, I used the modal that has the changed attribute.

```
SpecialModal = ModalView.extends({
    initialize: function() {
       this.paramsTemplate.footerClass = "white";
    } 
})
```

So, if I instanciate a normal Modal, this parameter is set! :'(

```
NormalModal = ModalView.extends({
    initialize: function() {
       console.log(this.paramsTemplate.footerClass);//shows 'white'!
    } 
})
```

Do you have any idea of how solving it?
thanks!

Comment: what is AlertingView? it seems working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/9/

Comment: Could you please show how you are constructing the views, that is, what parameters are you're passing into your views when you first instantiate them?

Comment: @aktiv-coder the fiddle works fine, because the class variable is not changed, this one here demonstrates the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/11/

This fiddle demonstrates your problem.

As long as you've not created any instance of `SpecialModal` every instance of `NormalModal` works.

This is because `paramsTemplate` is a class variable, not an instance variable. As soon as an instance of `SpecialModal` is created, it updates the classVariable and hence, all objects reflect that change.

Fortunately, I've just had a similar issue few days back [Backbone.js view instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630652/backbone-js-view-instance-variables/7630731#7630731)

**Solution :**

http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/12/

```
var ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className : "modal",
    initialize:function(){
        this.paramsTemplate= { footerClass: "" }   ;
    }
});
SpecialModal = ModalView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
       ModalView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
       this.paramsTemplate.footerClass = "white";
        console.log(this.paramsTemplate.footerClass);
    } 
})
NormalModal = ModalView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        ModalView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
       console.log(this.paramsTemplate.footerClass);
    } 
})
```

Comment: Not quite. `paramsTemplate` is an instance variable (or at least the JavaScript equivalent). If it was a "class variable" you'd say `ModelView.paramsTemplate` to access it and you'd define it in the *second* argument to `Backbone.View.extend`. The problem is the `paramsTemplate` is attached to the prototype is it is shared by all instances, assigning it in `initialize` attaches it to the instance rather then the prototype. This is a standard "don't put mutable data in the prototype" problem.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for insight, makes more sense now.